# Are event handlers guaranteed to run on the UI thread

Tags: c#, winforms

Are event handles like this

```
notifyIcon.BalloonTipClosed += new EventHandler(delegate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // ...
});
```

guaranteed to run on the UI thread, so I don't need to call `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` methods to update controls?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: of course. That's why you need to have any background thread to process some large execution task.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they are.

User interface events are caused by a message in the message queue, and it's the UI thread that runs the message pump that handles the messages.

An event from the [`System.Timers.Timer` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) would not run in the UI thread, because it's not an UI related event. An event from the [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) would run in the UI thread, as it's designed to run in a window and uses the message queue for the events.

Comment: upvoted for the clear distinction between the UI related event handlers and not related. I added this also to my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To be clear - event handlers for events raised by UI objects should be. Event handlers, *in general*, no.

E.g. event handlers for [NetworkAvailabilityChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkavailabilitychanged.aspx) won't be called on the UI thread.

But within the classes for e.g the System.Windows.Forms namespace, yes, they should be.

Answer (score 2):

Event Handlers, that are associated with the UI, run on the UI thread, the primary thread of a desktop application. That's the reason in some cases your UI may be get frozen. This is happening because the event handler's code takes too much to be executed in these cases. For this reason, we have adopted the paradigm of asynchronous programming. So when we have to wait for an I/O or a network related task to be completed, it's ins't needed this to be done by the UI thread. This can be done by another thread. Doing so, we avoid to freeze the UI.